# Reactions of Alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry

During my organic chemistry lesson, I was told that the reason why alkenes are low in reactivity is that their sigma bonds have very low polarity.

Why is this the case?

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Is ``alekenes`` meant to say alkenes. If so then your question doesn't seem to make much sense. If not, then what is is supposed to say. Please clarify you question.

Comment: @bon sorted! Now check the question!

Comment: Alkenes are not "low in reactivity". Alkanes are.